# MySql Shared lookup table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relationships

I've got two 'event' type tables, both of which can have a list of 'users' involved with the event.  I'd like to use a common lookup table for the users, but I'm not sure how to setup the FKs.

```
Highlight:
|ID   |Details|

Event:
|ID   |Details|

Contacts:
|event_id  |highlight_id  |user  |type |
```

This doesn't really work, as event_id and/or highlight_id could be null depending on which event type I'm dealing with.

I'd like to avoid a lookup table for each event if possible

Comment: Could you combine the event and highlights into a single table with a type field to distinguish? If not, then I think you'll need a single user_event lookup table for each.

Comment: @deanosaur, unfortunately, no.  Each event type is just different enough that there would be a lot of nulls in a combined table. i.e. Highlight has a title element, event doesn't, event has two more text fields than a highlight (gotta love managers designing content.....)

Comment: The contacts table you've layed out implies a relation between event and hightlight, which is not how you described the problem. I'd use two lookup tables (user_highlight and juser_event) unless there is a real user_event_highlight relationship.

Comment: Thanks.  There's no relationship between event and highlight other than the same user accounts that can be attached to event and/or highlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd definitely use separate lookup tables for user_event and user_highlight. Unless there is good reason to create a user_id|event_id|highlight_id relation (row), then it makes little sense to define it that way.

```
events
+-----+
event_id
detail

highlights
+---------+
highlight_id
detail

users
+----+
user_id

user_event
+---------+
user_id  (FK)
event_id (FK)

user_highlight
+-------------+
user_id       (FK)
highlight_id  (FK)
```